# Utilising available method syntax within Generic Repository Pattern

Tags: c#, linq, generics

So we are using C# with a generic repository to do some stuff like retrieving records from db. So we have something like this in our implementation class.

```
    public async Task<IList<TEntity>> GetAllAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = (predicate != null) ? context.Set<TEntity>().Where(predicate) : context.Set<TEntity>();
        return await query.ToListAsync();   
    }
```

Here we use the where clause to do some filtering. Where we are facing a bit of difficulty is how to take advantage of the LINQ extension methods available to us. Now we have a service which uses the generic repository class through a Unit of Work. I have omitted the unit of work for simplicity.

```
    public async Task<List<Product>> GetStockTransactionsAsync(string warehouse, string product)
    {
        var stockTransation= await _unitOfWork.stockRepository.GetAllAsync(p => p.product == product && p.warehouse == warehouse);
        return null;
    }
```

Say we now just want to use LINQ method syntax, something like this would work in our Service class method.

```
    var stockTransation= (await _unitOfWork.stockRepository.GetAllAsync(p => p.product == product && p.warehouse == warehouse)).Take(5);
```

By doing this we have ruined the IQueryable stuff that I really was keen to maintain, due to the size large size of the db; we want to run SQL, not do anything in memory.

Is there a good way to pass in LINQ method syntax like we would a predicate for where or what we do for select or includes. So we could use Take(n), Max, Sum() etc... all within the generic repository methods. Does anyone know a good approach for this?

Comment: IMHO generic repository patterns with unit of work are over complicating things here. it is really normal and good practise to do things like `await dbContext.Stocks.Where(p => p.product == product && p.warehouse == warehouse).Take(5).ToListAsync();`

Comment: Change the return type of your generic repository to `IQueryable` instead of `IList`?

Comment: If I return IQueryable to the service then it's in memory we need SQL to run this.

Comment: Also, I usually create a "concrete" repository per entity that inherits from an abstract generic repository which handles the linq query syntax based on the input parameters. Then you can provide your app layer with in-memory collections instead of allowing "pass-through" queryable access and keep all the heavy lifting in one place.

Comment: Can you just return `context.Set<TEntity>()` from your repository and work with it in your service? In this case, `GetAllAsync` can be implemented at LINQ-like extension method which takes `IQueryable` and returns `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you complicating it too much.
You can simply return `IQueryable<TEntity>` from your repository:

```
public interface IGenericRepository
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> Set<TEntity>();
}

public class EntityFrameworkRepository : IGenericRepository
{  
    // ...
    public IQueryable<TEntity> Set<TEntity>()
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}

// usage
IGenericRepository repository = ...;
var stockTransation = repository.Set<Product>()
    .Where(p => p.product == product && p.warehouse == warehouse)
    .Take(5)
    .ToArray();
```

In this case, SQL query will be generated and executed only after `.ToArray()` to take only 5 items matching this condition - no in-memory filtering will be done.

If you need to implement any custom methods, you can do it as extension methods in LINQ-alike way:

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    // This one doesn't make much sense, actually
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return predicate == null
            ? queryable
            : queryable.Where(predicate);
    }
}

// usage
IGenericRepository repository = ...;
var stockTransation = repository.Set<Product>()
    .GetAll(p => p.product == product && p.warehouse == warehouse)
    .Take(5) 
    .ToArray();
```

I have implemented it in synchronous way to make it simpler, but it can easily be translated into async code.

Comment: So by doing it this way we are still executing a db query not in memory and can keep the DAL out of the service by just passing an object. We have to ensure our service doesn't know our Data Access Layer. Thanks for taking up your time with me. Would you agree with what I have said here?

Comment: `IQueryable<>`s allow for delayed execution and are only evaluated upon iteration. Returning an `IQueryable` doesn't return a resultset, simply the query expression to be executed.

Comment: @P.Joe: Note that Entity Framework provides both the generic repository *and* unit of work patterns. This is why wrapping it in a generic repository / unit of work pattern merely complicates the solution.